# <button type="submit"> instead <input type="submit"> cakephp jsHelper

Tags: cakephp, helper, formhelper

with the cakePHP jsHelper :

```
<?php echo $this->Js->submit(__('Search'),array('class'=>'btn btn-info','div'=>false));?>
```

this will generate something like this :

```
<input  class="btn btn-info" id="submit-561877025" type="submit" value="Search"/>
```

But i need something like this :

```
<button  class="btn btn-info" id="submit-561877025" type="submit">Search</button>
```

is there any dynamic solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $this->Js->submit(__('Search'),array('class'=>'btn btn-info','type'=>'button','div'=>false));?>
```